# Run script on multiple tabs

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to run this script on selected tabs (MasterSheet, Jess, Carlos, Julian etc). I can get it working but it runs an error "input must fall within specified range' for any tabs that are not MasterSheet.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

```
function onEdit () {
  
var start = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
var current = start.getActiveCell() 

// refer to worksheets
var list = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TeacherData")

var main = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MasterSheet")


//has user selected category

if (current.getColumn()==2)
{
  
  //copy selected criteria
  var choice = current.getValue()
  list.getRange(1, 12).setValue(choice)
  
  
  //clear validation
  main.getRange(2,3,500).clearDataValidations()
  
  //create the rule
  var point = current.offset(0,1)
  var items = list.getRange(1,11,20)
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(items,true).build();
  
  //clear content
  point.clearContent();
  point.setDataValidation(rule)
  
}  
  
}
```

Comment: What line did the "input must fall within specified range" occur? Also, kindly include a sample spreadsheet and the stack trace of your script in your post above.

Comment: What is the goal of your script? I tried running your code based on the sample spreadsheet you've provided in the answer below and it has no error.

Comment: I'm simply trying to use dependent dropdown lists on various sheets to track some internal team information.  I can get the MasterSheet to work, but any subsequent copies return '"input must fall within specified range' in Column 'C'. Am not sure how to make the script work on future copies. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Replace your code above with the code that causes your script to fail and include a screenshot of stack trace (errors).

Answer (score 0):

you need to change var

```
 main =   
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MasterSheet")
    
    var main = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Jess")
    var main = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Carlos")
```

and so on

take a look here:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#setActiveSheet(Sheet)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick response.  I'm not sure I've fully understood but have tried the following which still doesn't work.
function onEdit () {
var start = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
var current = start.getActiveCell() 
// refer to worksheets
var list = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TeacherData")
// refer to activesheet
main = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MasterSheet")
var main = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Jess")
var main = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Carlos")

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CnKVIfAZ0OXPyMDfebb_Sjf679TbloYFQhuQwLLmCIU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Each time you use var main = you are overwriting the previous declaration try and do something like; 


var teacherSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TeacherData")

var masterSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MasterSheet")`